# Spring multiple Data Source configuration - Auto Fail over mechanism

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I would like to know if Spring offers any support for Auto Fail over of Data Sources? For example, if the primary data source is down, connect to secondary. Any suggestions to effectively configure auto fail over of Data sources is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I hope not because it would be a mistake, failover should be managed by the driver itself not by any framework like spring

Comment: which DB do you use?

Comment: this might help https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

Comment: DB used is Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The Primary/DR setup for DB should be managed at DB level. Its not right to switch that in code. But to answer your question "can connect to 2 Data sources in Spring". Yes you can easier if you are using Spring-boot.

Few details from spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-a-datasource).

Mark one of them as @Primary if you are using the default auto-configuration for JDBC or JPA (then that one will be picked up by any @Autowired injections).

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.primary")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Comment: What scenario would cause the datasource is linked to the secondary? When the Builder returns null?

Comment: This config won't handle failover scenarios. The autowiring will happen when the app starts up.